# .htacces redirect to new domain if file or folder not found

Tags: linux, .htaccess

**if my site is  domain.com   and if i go to  domain.com/1  and the folder 1 dont exist can i redirect via .htacces  to domain2.com/1**

if file or folder exist i like to show that file or folder but if not exist  then to redirect to new domain

*example:  if file.html dont exist in my server then*

example.com/file.html redirect to newdomain.com/file.html

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ newdomain.com/$1
```

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)  has more information about the types of questions that should be asked here. There are other [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/)  sites that are more appropriate for this type of question. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `http://` bit:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R]
```

otherwise, mod_rewrite will interpret that as a URL or file path and attempt to look for a directory called "newdomain.com". If you want the redirect to be permanent, change the `R` flag to `R=301`.